# Program exits too early

Tags: python

My code is working properly the only thing I want to change in my program is after congratulations message the program should ask user again to input a number until user input zero as quit.
Til now if I run my code after congratulations message program exits.

```
import random
import datetime

e = datetime.datetime.now()
print(e.strftime("%B %d,%Y @ %H:%M:%S"))

number = random.randint(1, 100)
print(number)
name = input("\nEnter your name: ")
 
 
def main():

    print(f"Hi, {name}, Welcome to the Guessing Number Game ")
    x = eval(input("Enter a number between 1 and 100, or 0 to quit: "))
    if x == 0:
        print("You quit? Goodbye!")
    else:
        playGuessingGame(x)


def playGuessingGame(x):
    times = 1
    while number != x:
        times += 1
        if x < number:
            print("Too low, try again")
            x = eval(input("Enter a number between 1 and 100, or 0 to quit: "))
 
        elif x > number:
            print("Too high, try again")
            x = eval(input("Enter a number between 1 and 100, or 0 to quit: "))

    print(f"Congratulations {name}!, you guessed the right number with {times} tries!")
 

main()
```

After congratulations message the program should ask user again to input a number until user input zero as quit.

Comment: (1) Fix the indentation of the code. (2) Generally you can wrap the relevant code in a "while True:" loop and "break" out of it when necessary.

Comment: Can you exactly tell me where do I have to change?

Answer (score 0):

since you have not added `break` inside `while` loop in `playGuessingGame()`. so program continuously asking to enter number even though you have entered zero

```
def playGuessingGame(x):
    times = 1
    while number != x:
        times += 1
        if x < number:
            print("Too low, try again")
            x = eval(input("Enter a number between 1 and 100, or 0 to quit: "))
            break     #since this was missing, program doesn't break the while loop

        elif x > number:
            print("Too high, try again")
            x = int(input("Enter a number between 1 and 100, or 0 to quit: "))
            break     #since this was missing, program doesn't break the while loop
```

Comment: Enter a number between 1 and 100, or 0 to quit: 60
Too low, try again
Enter a number between 1 and 100, or 0 to quit: 70
Congratulations IA!, you guessed the right number with 2 tries!Enter a number between 1 and 100, or 0 to quit       this is how I want my output